# unable to shift numeric values from Javascript to php,not using <form>

Tags: javascript, php

This value of count is to be transferred to the php page orderdetail.php 
    This is the javascript code that i am using,Please provide the solution.

```js
 
    var count=10;
    $.post('orderdetail.php',{no_of_orders:count},function(){});
```

The php code i am using is

```
<?php
    $no_of_orders=$_POST['no_of_orders'];
    echo $no_of_orders; 
?>
```

Comment: pass `count` to `no_of_orders`, `{no_of_orders: count}`

Comment: What is `new1` in your js? What the output of your php snippet?

Comment: @JosanIracheta where should i write it?

Comment: @simon.ro there is count instead of new1, the php snippet produces output of "undefined index:'no_of_orders'

Comment: You never stated the problem in your question.

Comment: @epascarello Well that's what question is saying

Comment: *"This value of count is to be transferred to the php page orderdetail.php This is the javascript code that i am using,Please provide the solution."* That does not say what your problem is. The code shows an Ajax call to a PHP sending the values. Seems like that should be working. What is not happening?

Comment: @epascarello the value is  not transferring to the php page

Comment: So you make the Ajax request and than are going to the php page and expect the value to be there? Or you are not seeing the values in the Ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use the php instead of including javascript for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

> Using jQuery to set the **value** of the input field with the id
>   **myVal**. Then you can send the value with the **Form**

**JS/jQuery CODE**

```
var count=10;
$('#myVal').val(count);
```

**HTML/PHP CODE**

```
<form action="orderdetail.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="" id="myVal" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: just need to transfer count to the php page